# PHP time is 1 hour off

Tags: php

I've already set the timezone setting in php.ini but its 1 hour ahead of the timezone I have set.

I thought this would be covered already in here, but the only solution I can find is telling me to check the timezone, which I have and it's correct.

I have "America/Toronto" set. I live in Toronto and it's not the right time.

The solution to the question marked as duplicate did not work for me.

Is there something about day light savings I need to check?

Comment: Is your timezone set to a UTC time (like GMT or UTC+1) or a place (like Europe/London).

Comment: It's set to a place, "America/Toronto"

Comment: Solution: I contacted my web host and the time was permanently incorrect and they said they won't change it because it will mess up other users.

Answer (score 0):

If you've set your timezone to a non-geographical setting, then it will never reflect daylight savings time, so `"GMT"` will always be equal to UTC as it is non-geographical.

If you set your timezone to a geographical location then if that place has DST then it will be reflected in the timezone. For example `"Europe/London"` is UTC in the winter and UTC+1 in the summer, as per the local time.

There are places that do not observe DST though, so in the USA `"America/Denver"` is Mountain Time with DST, and `"America/Phoenix"` is without DST.

You can find a list of all valid PHP timezones at http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Hope this make sense.

Comment: I have "America/Toronto" set. I live in Toronto and it's not the right time.

Comment: Try printing your default time to see if it's correct. Use `echo date_default_timezone_get();`

Comment: prints `America/Toronto`

Comment: My PHP tells me it's 09:23 in Toronto. Is that right?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. My site says 10:23.

Comment: Sounds like a server time problem. If you can't change the server time, use a workaround from the next timezone west. Try `"America/Chicago"`.

Comment: Chicago shows the real time in Toronto. So they're all off by 1 hour.